# Missing title in Ionic ion-view

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

For some reason I cannot get the Ionic title to show up: http://codepen.io/hawkphil/pen/oXqgrZ?editors=101

This code is not exactly 100% following Ionic example but I don't want to add 2 layers of state (`/` and `/somethingelse`) just to do a simple page including top and bottom.

**HTML**

```
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>

    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
      <button class="button button-clear">
        OK
      </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-view view-title="{{ title }}">
    <ion-content class=" has-header">
      test test
      </<ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = '<b>BOLD TITLE</b>';
});
```

**Is there a way to fix this?** I need a way to show dynamic title with HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to show view directly, independent of routing by `ui-router`,then it should be `ion-nav-view` instead of `ion-nav` & then for changing `nav` header `ion-header-bar`, & then for binding HTML on the ion title you could use the answer suggest by @shushanthp.

**Code**

```
<ion-nav-view view-title="{{ title }}">
  <ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-balanced bar">
    <span ng-bind-html="title"></span>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content class=" has-header">
    test test
  </<ion-content>
</ion-nav-view>
```

[**Forked Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdodNm)

Comment: This works but the css seems wrong as the title now left aligned. Any idea? Also I do have left back button in my real app

Comment: @HP. its like you are creating custom header..you need to add those buttons manually

Answer (score 2):

Your `<ion-view>` should be inside a `<ion-nav-view>` which is a part of `ui-router` as stated in the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/). You have to set up some basic routing for the dynamic header to be updated.

I've customized your codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwVwwW)

Comment: Thanks but as mentioned, I cannot add hierarchy of routing for specific reason.